# Unix command to list all the files and directories in the current directory whose second character is a digit

Tags: unix, grep, pipe, ls, filepattern

My code for this is
`ls | grep .[0-9]*`

And the output is showing as

```
d2
d4
di3
dir1
f1
f2
fil4
file3
g2t
g3t
```

The expected output is

```
d2
d4
f1
f2
g2t
g3t
```

I know i can directly use `ls ?[0-9]` but then my output order is different

```
f1  f2  g2t  g3t

d2:

d4:
```

Comment: `ls | grep .[0-9].*`

Comment: If you're going to pipe `ls` to `grep` (which you shouldn't do), you need to anchor the pattern.  eg `grep '^.[0-9]'` But there are many issues with this.  Use `find`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this worked
`ls -d ?[0-9]*`

Answer (score 0):

This find command lists the files and directories in the current directory whose names have a second character that is a digit

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '?[0-9]*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , It will work

```
ls -1 | grep '^.[0-9][.]*'
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit?